# How to display UTF characters in message line of gVim?

Tags: vim, vi

I am using a German version of gVim 7.4 on Windows 7. 
The message line does not display UTF-8 characters correctly.
For example, it shows

```
Wort zu ~/vimfiles/spell/de.utf-8.add hinzugef<fc>gt
```

instead of

```
Wort zu ~/vimfiles/spell/de.utf-8.add hinzugefügt
```

after having added a word to the spelling directory. 
How can I make it display the umlaut?

Comment: What's your value of `:set encoding?`?

Comment: `:set ecoding` returns `encoding=utf-8`

Comment: Interesting. So this is just about the message line, umlauts in buffer work fine, right? Does `:echo "hinzugefügt"` work?

Comment: The `echo`command works perfectly. The buffer and file encoding work as expected and are both set to `utf-8`, too. I also searched my settings using `:opt`, but I found nothing that gave me a hint on a supposedly wrong encoding.

Comment: One more interesting observation: When I change to input mode, the bold message
`--EINFÜGEN--` is displayed correctly. The same is true for all other messages displayed
in bold. What is special about these kinds of messages?

Comment: Okay, which Vim version do you use? Could you try a newer one?

Comment: What about other messages, e.g. `:echo has_key(1,1)` should return `E715: Wörterbuch benötigt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem related to the charset converter for gvim on windows, 
From `help :usr_45`, it says:

> Using different languages only works when Vim was compiled to handle
>     it.  To find out if it works, use the ":version" command and check the
>     output for "+gettext" and "+multi_lang".  If they are there, you are
>     OK.  If you see "-gettext" or "-multi_lang" you will have to find
>     another Vim.

If there is 
 "-gettext" or "-multi_lange", or "-iconv", you need to download proper library your own 
for windows, see this post https://superuser.com/questions/207264/gvim-utf-8-in-windows for 
more information and downlinks for the library on windows

Comment: I tried this but it changed nothing. But the `:language` command returned the following output
    `Momentane Sprache: "LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252;[...]`

Comment: I think, the number refers to the Windows-1252 encoding. Obviously, the `:language` command did not affect this setting. I could also set the language to French and it did not change. The problem with the non-displayable characters remains the same.

Comment: i don't know you are from austria, from your `:language` output, i guess it should be some problem related to the locale settings. you could also try `language message de_at.utf-8` or `language message de_at.1252`, hope it will help

Comment: or maybe it's because you lack proper charset converter library for you new installed givm, see this post, it may help with your problem http://superuser.com/questions/207264/gvim-utf-8-in-windows

Comment: Thanks, @SamuelDSR, the link you provided solved my problem! I think you should edit your answer above and add this information. Then I can mark your answer as solution for my problem.